# Gauss Jordan code for mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I want to find the inverse of the matrix using a unit matrix. I know it's done directly using Inverse, but I need to write a simple code. I can't write because I'm just starting to learn. How can I write this?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you are asking for but `RowReduce` performs the Gauss-Jordan elimination.

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1, 1} 3];
Ainv = RowReduce[
    Join[A, IdentityMatrix[Length[A]], 2]
    ][[All, Length[A] + 1 ;;]];
```

Test:

```
Max[Abs[Ainv - Inverse[A]]]
```

> 1.11022*10^-16